# How do I change number of columns in a proper way in twentyfourteen child theme?

Tags: javascript, child-theme, theme-twenty-fourteen

I'm trying to deactive and reactive a javascript in my childtheme - from the twentyfourteen theme (so updates won't effect things).

What I really want to do is to change column width from 4 to 3 in the footer but I don't want to change /js/functions.js directly in the main theme (maybe there is another/better way achieving this. please tell!)

I'm putting this in functions.php in the child-theme:

```
/* activate and decative js class */
class aadjs {
    public function __construct() {
        add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', array( $this, 'deactivejs'), 100 );
    }

    public function deactivejs() {
        wp_dequeue_script( 'twentyfourteen-script' ); 
        add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', array( $this, 'reactivatejs'), 100);
    }

    //Why isn't this function executed?
    public function reactivatejs() {
        echo  get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/functions.js'; 
        exit;       
        wp_enqueue_script( 'twentyfourteen-script', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/functions.js', array( 'jquery' ), '20140616', true );
    }               

}
$x = new aadjs();
```

I want to deactive js and then reactive js but reactivatejs is not called. What am I doing wrong? The path to the new js file in the child-theme is set correctly and it does exist.

The /js/functions.js I want to change:

```
_window.load( function() {
        // Arrange footer widgets vertically.
        if ( $.isFunction( $.fn.masonry ) ) {
            $( '#footer-sidebar' ).masonry( {
                itemSelector: '.widget',
                columnWidth: function( containerWidth ) {
                    return containerWidth / 4;
                },
                gutterWidth: 0,
                isResizable: true,
                isRTL: $( 'body' ).is( '.rtl' )
            } );
        }

    } );
```

**TO** (notice the 3)

```
_window.load( function() {
        // Arrange footer widgets vertically.
        if ( $.isFunction( $.fn.masonry ) ) {
            $( '#footer-sidebar' ).masonry( {
                itemSelector: '.widget',
                columnWidth: function( containerWidth ) {
                    return containerWidth / 3;
                },
                gutterWidth: 0,
                isResizable: true,
                isRTL: $( 'body' ).is( '.rtl' )
            } );
        }

    } );
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you are using `exit() in your`reactivatejs()` method as this breaks the method before it even loads your script (*hopefully this is for debugging purposes*).

I also do think that in is unnecessary to create a class to this, a simple spaghetti function would do perfectly. Anyways, if you need to use a class, the class's constructor is not suppose to any work, the constructor is suppose to initialize the class. You would want to to take your action outside of the constructor. Also, when it comes to removing scripts and styles, you would want to deregister and dequeue.

Here are possible solutions:

### CLOSURES - not really recommended as they cannot be removed

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', function ()
{
    // Remove your script
    wp_dequeue_script( 'twentyfourteen-script' );
    wp_deregister_script( 'twentyfourteen-script' );

    // Add new script
    wp_enqueue_script( 'lets-be-unique-here', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/functions.js', ['jquery'], '20140616', true );
}, 100 );
```

### NORMAL SPAGHETTI

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'addjs', 100 );
function addjs()
{
    // Remove your script
    wp_dequeue_script( 'twentyfourteen-script' );
    wp_deregister_script( 'twentyfourteen-script' );

    // Add new script
    wp_enqueue_script( 'lets-be-unique-here', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/functions.js', ['jquery'], '20140616', true );
}
```

### CLASS WITH ACTION OUTSIDE

```
class AddJS
{
    public function addjs ()
    {
        // Remove your script
        wp_dequeue_script( 'twentyfourteen-script' );
        wp_deregister_script( 'twentyfourteen-script' );

        // Add new script
        wp_enqueue_script( 'lets-be-unique-here', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/functions.js', ['jquery'], '20140616', true );
    }
}
```

**THEN**

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', ['AddJS','addjs'], 100 );
```

**OR**

```
$addjs = new AddJS();
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', [$addjs,'addjs'], 100 );
```

### CLASS WITH ACTION INSIDE CLASS

```
class AddJS
{
    public function addAction ()
    {
        add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', [$this,'addjs'], 100 );
    }

    public function addjs ()
    {
        // Remove your script
        wp_dequeue_script( 'twentyfourteen-script' );
        wp_deregister_script( 'twentyfourteen-script' );

        // Add new script
        wp_enqueue_script( 'lets-be-unique-here', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/functions.js', ['jquery'], '20140616', true );
    }
}
$addjs = new AddJS();
$addjs->addjs();
```